# Partition at 51% with df while folders are empty?

Tags: docker, df, debian-buster

I need some help on this one.

I use a test server which is Debian 10 with Docker's containers (all these inside a XCP-NG server).

```
# df -h
Sys. de fichiers      Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
/dev/xvda11              32G     15G   15G  51% /data
//localnetwork/Download   8,2T    4,8T  3,5T  59% /data/downloaded
```

My issue is about these 15G used in /data. Sub-folders into /data are /data/torrent and 2 others directories I never used.

du -xca into these folders show them empty

I messed up at the begining because :

- /data/downloaded was, at first, part of my /data partition.
- After that I tried to mount my NAS with NFS but uid were to
  complicated to do as users were already in use both side
- Since then, I use cifs

While I was playing with nfs, 2 files finished and probably got in pending state as it was impossible to move to /data/downloaded because of permissions.

Now the setup is working fine, except I have these 15 GB in /data I don't see no matter what I try :
du -xca & ls -alh return empty folders

After some googling, I tried

```
# lsof +L1
```

&

```
# lsof +L | grep torrent
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.sshfs file system /tmp/.x2go-az/spool/C-az-50-1590501658_stDMATE_dp32
      Output information may be incomplete.
bash       33859                             media  cwd       DIR             202,11      4096     2    1177345 /data/torrents
```

Hence I decided to do it easy mode, just reboot (well it's not a prod server after all)
The line disappeared but df still showing 15 Gb.
I checked /data/lost+found folder but it's empty too.

I'm out of idea so if you have any, your are more than welcome :)

Comment: Run `mount -o bind /data/ /mnt/`. Check your directories again while it is mounted there. Most probably you have files in `/data/downloaded/` and have mounted the network path over them.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible. Thanks I have some files in this folders.